# What is a 'large number, represented as an array of decimal digits'. Is it the sum of the numbers in the array?

Tags: algorithm

Write a C function that returns 1 if a large number, represented as an array of decimal digits, is exactly divisibly by 7, otherwise 0. The number has n decimal digits.

int div7(int number[], int n)

That is the question.

Does he mean that I have to add the numbers in the array which is the 'large number'?

But it is also an int, so it wouldn't have decimal places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you shouldn't sum the numbers. The number 279 would be represented as `{2,7,9}`, for example. 279 is divisible by 7, but 2+7+9 isn't.

Comment: I see. So int number[3] of [1,2,3] and n = 2 would be 1.23 like that?

Comment: Presumably `n` would always be exactly equal to the number of elements of the array. So `[1,2,3]` and n=2 is not a valid example, but `[1,2,3]` and n=3 is. The big number is always going to be an integer (in the mathematical sense, not necessarily the programming sense. The number might be much larger than `INT_MAX`)

Comment: but "The number has n decimal digits" so the number would always be a decimal unless n = 0 right?

Comment: I assume "decimal digits" means "the total number of digits in the decimal representation of the number" rather than "the number of digits appearing after the decimal point". 123 has 3 decimal digits. 456.789 has 6 decimal digits.

Comment: You have no chance to get the length of an array in C. That is what the parameter `n` is for. "Divisible" is usually only defined for integer numbers, there surely is no decimal point.

Comment: I see. that makes more sense considering it's an int and looks to see if it's divisible by 7. Thanks!